# How to close a dialog and return another link (not go back)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, dialog

I want closed dialog open page2 not go back page1.

I tried bind `pagehide` event on dialog like this, but it first goes back page1 then open page2, not direct open page2.

```js
$("#dialog").bind("pagehide", function() {
  $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
});
```

```html
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
  <div data-role="content">
    page1
    <a href="#dialog" data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="slide">open dialog</a>
    <a href="#page2" data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="slide">open page2</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
  <div data-role="content">page2</div>
  <a href="#page1" data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="slide">open page1</a>
</div>
<div data-role="dialog" id="dialog">
  <div data-role="header"><h1>dialog</h1></div>
  <div>Dialog</div>
</div>
```

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: @Omar jquery v2.1.0, jquery mobile v1.4.2, and Iam sorry. I try use `window.history.pushState`, it is work now.

Comment: @Omar I'm sorry, my mistake, I used `pagehide` before `window.history.pushState`, but because I was test on my Lumia 920's IE10, it does not support `window.history.pushState` I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQM 1.4 you define a page to look like a dialog by assigning `data-dialog="true"`:

```
<div data-dialog="true" id="dialog">
```

Then to redirect on close, you could handle it this way:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {
    $("body").on("pagecontainerbeforetransition", function (event, ui) {
        var oldpageid = $("body").pagecontainer("getActivePage").prop("id");
        var newpageid = ui.toPage.prop("id");
        if (oldpageid == "dialog" && newpageid == "page1") {
            $("body").pagecontainer("change", "#page2", {"transition": "slide"});
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Basically catch the page before transition, see if we are on dialog and are going to page1, if so, redirect to page2.

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7PhpZ/)**